# Editing a .jstyle file for JabRef

Tags: jabref

I am trying to edit my `.jstyle` file so as to fulfil [the requirements set out by The Canadian Journal of Chemical Engineering](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1939-019X/homepage/ForAuthors.html).

I am working with LibreOffice Version 5.1.3.2 on Windows 10. JabRef´s version is 3.4.

I have accomplished most of the things I need but two:

1. I need the citations to be superscripted, bracketed and in consecutive numbers.
2. I need to report just the initial page on the articles.

This is the `.jstyle` file I have managed to edit to do most of what I want:

```
NAME
Default [number] style file.

JOURNALS
Journal name 1
Journal name 2

PROPERTIES
Title="REFERENCES"
IsSortByPosition="true"
IsNumberEntries="true"
ReferenceParagraphFormat="-BodyParagraphStyle"
ReferenceHeaderParagraphFormat="-Heading1"

CITATION
BracketBefore="["
BracketAfter="]"
BracketBeforeInList="["
BracketAfterInList="] "
CitationSeparator="; "
UniquefierSeparator=","
GroupedNumbersSeparator="-"
MinimumGroupingCount="3"
FormatCitations="true"
CitationCharacterFormat="Default"
SuperscriptCitations="true"
PageInfoSeparator="; "

LAYOUT
article=\format[Authors(InitialsFirst,Semicolon)]{\author},  <i>\journal</i> <b>\year\uniq</b>, <i>\volume</i>,\begin{pages} \format[FormatPagesForHTML]{\pages}\end{pages}.

book=\format[Authors(InitialsFirst,Semicolon)]{\author}, <i>\title</i>, \edition edition, \publisher, \address <b>\year\uniq</b>, p.\begin{pages} \format[FormatPagesForHTML]{\pages}\end{pages}.

incollection=\format[Authors(LastFirst,Semicolon)]{\author} (<b>\year\uniq</b>). <i>\title</i>. In: \format[AuthorLastFirst,AuthorAbbreviator,AuthorAndsReplacer]{\editor} (Ed.), <i>\booktitle</i>, \publisher.

inbook=\format[Authors(LastFirst,Semicolon)]{\author} (<b>\year\uniq</b>). <i>\chapter</i>. In: \format[AuthorLastFirst,AuthorAbbreviator,AuthorAndsReplacer]{\editor} (Ed.), <i>\title</i>, \publisher.

phdthesis=\format[Authors(LastFirst,Semicolon)]{\author} (<b>\year\uniq</b>). <i>\title</i>, \school.

default=\format[Authors(LastFirst,Semicolon)]{\author} (<b>\year\uniq</b>). <i>\title</i>, \journal \volume\begin{pages} : \format[FormatPagesForHTML]{\pages}\end{pages}.
```

If anybody knows of a tutorial to edit `.jstyle` files I would appreciate it.